# Search Dialog box in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

I am using the search dialog box in jqgrid. The columns which has search attribute set as true will appear in the search dialog box.Can we have just column names instead of select drop down of columns in the search dialog box of JQGRID ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the pager add those lines

```
 jQuery("#list").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager',
              { edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: true, refresh: true },
              {},
             {
             },      
             {  
             },
             {
                 multipleGroup: true,
                 closeOnEscape: true,
                 caption: "Search...",
                 multipleSearch: true,
                 Find: "Find",
                 Reset: "Reset",
                 odata: [{ oper: 'eq', text: 'equal' }, { oper: 'ne', text: 'not equal' }, { oper: 'lt', text: 'less' }, { oper: 'le', text: 'less or equal' }, { oper: 'gt', text: 'greater' }, { oper: 'ge', text: 'greater or equal' }, { oper: 'bw', text: 'begins with' }, { oper: 'bn', text: 'does not begin with' }, { oper: 'in', text: 'is in' }, { oper: 'ni', text: 'is not in' }, { oper: 'ew', text: 'ends with' }, { oper: 'en', text: 'does not end with' }, { oper: 'cn', text: 'contains' }, { oper: 'nc', text: 'does not contain' }],
                 groupOps: [{ op: "AND", text: "all" }, { op: "OR", text: "any" }],
             }
             );
```