# Implementation of a search filter(range) in jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am using the search dialog box in jqgrid. 
The columns for which I wanted the filters, 
I just had need to set the search attribute as true.

Like this ::

```
{name:'Date',search = true}

{name:'Date 1',search : true}

$("#grid1").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager1', 
{edit:false, 
add:false, 
del:false, 
search:true, 
refresh: true},{}, {}, {}, {multipleSearch: true,closeAfterSearch: true,groupOps: [ { op: "AND", text: "AND" }]} );
```

With that it appears in the search dialog box.

**Can we have just column names instead of select drop down of columns in the search dialog box of JQGRID ?**

[image: Modified Image]

The latest Image:
[image: Image 2]

This is my code::

I tried with the two code snippets that you have provided with the following changes:

```
$.extend($.jgrid.search, {
    multipleSearch: true,
    closeAfterSearch: true,
    groupOps: [ { op: "AND", text: "AND" }],
    afterRedraw: function (p) {
        var $form = $(this);
        $form.find("select.opsel,input.add-rule,input.delete-rule,td.columns>select").hide();
        $form.find("td.operators>select").prop("disabled", true);
        $form.find("td.columns").append("<span>Due Date:<span>");
        setTimeout(function () {
           // set focus in the first input field
           $form.find('input[type="text"]:first').focus();
        }, 100);
    }
});

$grid.jqGrid("navGrid", "#pager", {add: false, edit: false, del: false, searchfunc: function (pSearch) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.jqGrid("setGridParam", {postData: {
        filters: {
            groupOp: "AND",
            rules: [
                { field: "dueDt", op: "le", "data": "" },
                { field: "dueDt", op: "ge", "data": "" }
            ]
        }
    }});
    $this.jqGrid("searchGrid", pSearch);
}});
```

The post data is

```
postData: {}
```

Comment: "select drop down of columns" is the **form** (the dropdown) in which information about columns will by displayed. I understand that you want to change the form and display the same information in *another form*, but you wrote only "Can we have just column names". It's just the information set and *not the form* in which you want to display the information. Could you describe more clear what you want to have?

Comment: @Oleg: Thanks for your response.
I have 3 columns. In this one of the column is the date for which the search is set as true. I want to search the grid on the basis of date range.

So what i exactly want is that the search dialog box should show two rows:


`Due Date less or equal date picker
Due Date greater or equal date picker`

The date picker i have added.
The drop down from the due date should be removed.

I am also seeing your after Redraw option usage.

Also see my attached image file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand your question you want

1. hide some controls of searching dialog
2. set the filter rule **before** the searching dialog will be opened. To be exact you need to set `AND` operation with two rules: "greater or equal" and "less or equal" to some columns.

I could imagine multiple implementations of the scenario. For example you can use `navGrid` with `search: false` option and use `navButtonAdd` to add the custom button which looks exactly like "Search" button. Alternatively you can use `searchfunc` parameter of `navGrid` to reset `postData.filters` to the filter which you need *before* calling of `searchGrid`. The both implementation will be very close.

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SearchRange.htm) demonstrates the second approach. I set parameters of Searching dialog by expending of `$.jgrid.search` to reduce usage of many empty (`{}`) parameters of `navgrid`:

```
$.extend($.jgrid.search, {
    multipleSearch: true,
    closeAfterSearch: true,
    groupOps: [ { op: "AND", text: "AND" }],
    afterRedraw: function (p) {
        var $form = $(this);
        $form.find("select.opsel,input.add-rule,input.delete-rule,td.columns>select").hide();
        $form.find("td.operators>select").prop("disabled", true);
        $form.find("td.columns").append("<span>Due Date:<span>");
        setTimeout(function () {
           // set focus in the first input field
           $form.find('input[type="text"]:first').focus();
        }, 100);
    }
});
```

Inside of `afterRedraw` I disable additionally the operations select:

[image]

The code which calls `navGrid` is the following:

```
$grid.jqGrid("navGrid", "#pager", {add: false, edit: false, del: false, searchfunc: function (pSearch) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.jqGrid("setGridParam", {postData: {
        filters: {
            groupOp: "AND",
            rules: [
                { field: "invdate2", op: "le", "data": "" },
                { field: "invdate1", op: "ge", "data": "" }
            ]
        }
    }});
    $this.jqGrid("searchGrid", pSearch);
}});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried this and it is showing me a single row in the search dialog box.
I saw your demo in that there are two dates but I have a single date column. I am attaching the output file that 
I am getting.

Comment: @SashiKant: Do you set `postData.filters` before calling of `searchGrid` like I do in my demo? I set `postData.filters` with **two** rules. So the dialog contains two inputs.

Comment: Thanks for your time bro, kindly check the question which I have updated now, I have added my code snippet. Can you send me exactly what code is required because I am relatively new in JQGRID coding

Comment: @SashiKant: You are welcome! The code which you added don't contains the part which creates the grid. If you have the demo online you can post the URL. Moreover it could be important to know which versions of jqGrid you use. I recommend you to use the current version [4.6.0](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6).

Comment: Hi Oleg, If you can check the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22474722/search-dialog-box-in-jqgrid

It is also related to this

Comment: @SashiKant: The question contains practically the same text like the original text of your question. I posted my first comment to your question to clear **the details**. Without knowing details one can't understand the question. Back to *your* current question. **Could you modify the code which you posted by including the part which creates the grid and which initialize `$grid` variable which you use?**

Comment: Let me clear out the things:

1) I have only one column of date which is Due Date. I want to have a range filter of date on Due Date column.
2) I tried with your two code snippets that you provided but when i am running it, gives me a search dialog which shows only single row for searching in that column. In the image that you have attached it shows two rows for searching. I want that dialog box.

Comment: @SashiKant: The error exists in **your code which you don't posted**. [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SearchRange1.htm) for example uses two rules with one Date column. [Another demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SearchRange2.htm) uses three rules and so on. So all should work. Sorry, but I can help you to localize the problem **in your code** only if you post the URL to the demo which reproduces the problem or if you post more full code which you use currently.

Comment: As you suggested, it is working with postData.filters.
There were some other data error, which is resolved now.
Thanks for your time and effort.. God bless you.. :-)

Comment: @SashiKant: You are welcome! The most important is that you have working solution now. All other intermediate steps are not really important.

Comment: Thanks.. I got the search dialog box as required and it is performing the searching also.
One issue that I am getting now is: When i am clicking the reset search it is reloding the grid but along with that it is giving me a js error. The error is in the file jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js and it states TypeError: a is null, line: 516. I did the analysis and found out that it is the datepicker object. So can it be the case of datepicker object that i am setting it in the col model. Can you suggest something in this.

Comment: @SashiKant: Sorry, but it's the description of the problem only. I suppose that you use `datepicker` in a wrong way. I could help you *only if you could see* the code which shows how you use `datepicker`. In my demo for example I call `datepicker` in `searchoptions.dataInit` and I use do this inside of `setTimeout(..., 50);`. What you do?

Comment: I am using this searchoptions: {dataInit: function (el) { $(el).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy'}); }}
in my col model. Can you show your code snippet for datePicker. The datePicker is working fine in search dialog box, the error that i am getting is while I am clicking on the reload button after searching the grid.

Comment: @SashiKant: You need just open my demo, click on the right mouse button to see context menu of the web browser and then choose "View source" item in Internet Explorer, "View page source" item in Google Chrome or something with close name in other web browser. In the way you will see full code of HTML page with embedded JavaScript code. In your case you need to use `dataInit: function (el) { setTimeout(function () { $(el).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy'}); }, 100);`. In the case the call `datepicker` will be done 100ms **later** after the `el` element will be placed on HTML page.